# Add custom query info when using Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query in laravel:

```
$draftOrders = DraftOrder::all()->toArray();
```

However I need to convert the "last_modified" field, like that in normal MySQL usage:

```
date_format(`last_modified`,'%Y/%m/%e %H:%i:%s')
```

How do I fit that in the Laravel eloquent query?

Comment: Use the `DB::raw` of laravel

Comment: you can use update_at, it does require to define updated_at field in your table. It will meet the requirement that you want with less code.

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel you can use Carbon to format the dates:

```
$date =  Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y/m/e H:i:s:');
```

Or if you want format the date in your query you can use:

```
DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(last_modified, "%Y/%m/%e %H:%i:%s")')
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Doc :

> By default, Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at columns on your database table automatically. Simply add these timestamp columns to your table and Eloquent will take care of the rest. If you do not wish for Eloquent to maintain these columns, add the following property to your model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
   // to allow laravel to manage created_at or updated_at just
   // coment or delete the line below
   public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Hope this help.